# nestJs & SoketIo - nestJs server connected but not emit messages

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io, nestjs

I am trying to build a bot that connect Facebook to my backend , i want to show the conversation in real time in web app made with vite (react )  when i receive message from Facebook to my backend and emit it to all connected client i get  nothing in my web console  only onModuleInit  showing socket connected fine ,**but when i try to send from postman it work fine

NB : when i use postman it work fine**

this is socket Gateway in nest

```
// socket gateway

// socket.gateway.ts
import { OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  ConnectedSocket,
  MessageBody,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';

import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway({ cors: '*' })
export class SocketGateway implements OnModuleInit {
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  // socket: Socket;
  constructor() {
    this.server = new Server();
  }
  onModuleInit() {
    this.server.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log('Client connected', socket.id);
      socket.emit('newMessage', 'server connected fine ');
      // this.socket = socket;
    });
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('newMessage')
  onMessage(@MessageBody() data: string) {
    console.log('Message received');
    // this.socket.emit('newMessage', data);
    this.server.emit('newMessage', {
      message: data,
    });
  }

  sendToAll(msg: string) {
    this.server.emit('newMessage', msg);
  }
    
}
```

this is how i call the function to emit from the controller`

```
async sendMessageToCFS_Socket(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
    if (this.socketGateway.server) {
      this.socketGateway.server.emit('newMessage', message);
      this.socketGateway.sendToAll(message);
      console.log('send message to socket ');
    } else {
      console.error('Socket server is not initialized.');
    }
  }
```

this is what i have in backend console
*the messsage
send message to socket*

and this is how i get the message in my frontend

```
useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:3000/");
    console.log(socket);
    setSocket(socket);

    // Handle incoming messages
    socket.on("newMessage", (data) => {
      console.log("Message from NestJS received: ", data);
    });
    // Log socket events for debugging
    socket.onAny((event, ...args) => {
      console.log(`Socket event received: ${event}`, args);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

and i get in frontend console server connected
when i send message throw my app i receive nothing in my frontend

Comment: Can try listening on `connect_error` event specifically and see if there's any errors? https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-socket-instance/#connect_error ? Also on client side are you using the `socket.io-client` library?

Comment: no there is no error and i  use the socket.io-client plus it work when i send anything from postman